# Why is the declaration of the array of generic type correct?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

We cannot create the array of generic type, it's a well-known fact, so I'm not going to provide formal references to JLS here. But we can *declare* such arrays as follows:

```
static <E> void reduce() {
    List<Integer>[] arr; //compiles fine
    E[] avv;             //compiles fine 
    avv = new E[10];       //doesn't compile
    arr = new List<Integer>[10]; //doesn't compile
}
```

Anyone know the reason for such declarations?

Comment: If you weren't able to declare a generic array (as variable, field or method parameter), how could a class made use of generics anyway?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I assume you meant

```
avv = new E[2];             //doesn't compile
arr = new List<Integer>[2]; //doesn't compile
```

in the last two lines of your method. You have to specify the size of the array when to create a new array. The code still doesn't compile, though.

Arrays predate generics. Arrays are present since the first version of Java, while generics were only added in version 1.5. To break no old code, the Java designers decided to erase generic types at runtime: at runtime, a type parameters are replaced by their upper bound. In your case, at runtime, `E` is the same as `Object`. It is not known which type `E` is really.

This is a problem, because, the array element type is not erased at runtime. `Integer[]` and `String[]` are different types, even at runtime. If you write `new E[2]`, the Java runtime doesn't know what kind of array it must create. It could be `String[]` or `Integer[]`, or any other array type. Therefore, you cannot create new arrays with generic elements.

Arrays with generic elements are still allowed as types, mainly in order to use them in method parameters:

```
<E> E doSomething(E[] param) { ... }
```

The actual array is created in another part of the program, where its type is known. You could call this method with

```
String result = doSomething(new String[2]);
```

for example.

Answer (score 1):

It allows you to pass arrays of generic types as method parameters.

For example:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public void bar (T[] arr) {}
}

...

Foo<String> foo = new Foo<String>();
String[] arr = {"aa","bb");
foo.bar (arr);
```

If `T[]` wasn't allowed, the method signature would have to be `public void bar (Object[] arr)`, and the compiler would let you pass any type of array to that method.